# Ошибка в паскале: "Нет перегруженной подпрограммы с такими типами параметров"

Tags: pascal

```
program x;

var x,y:real;
begin
  writeln('введите значение х ');
  readln(x);

  if x<=2 then
    y:=(3*(exp(sin(x))))*(sin(2*x)) / (cos(2*x)) 
  else
  if (3<x) and (x<4) then
    y:=(2.47*(ln(x)/ln(10))+(exp((2*x)*ln(x))))
  else
  if (x>=6) then
    y:=((sqrt(abs((cos*cos)*x)+6)+(4))); //тут выдает ошибку  

  writeln('при x=',x:6:3,'y=',y:6:2);
end.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ошибка в `(cos*cos)*x` , исправление зависит от того, что нужно посчитать,но аргумент в `cos()` точно нужно передать